# How to convert List of Maps to CSV

Tags: java, list, csv, dictionary

I need to convert List of Maps to CSV object which should like below

```
List<Map<String,Object>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
```

maps object contains the value in below format

map 1 :

```
(header 1, value1)

(header 2, value2)

(header 3, value3)

(header 4, value4)
```

map 2 :

```
(header 1, value5)

(header 2, value6)

(header 3, value7)

(header 4, value8)
```

I am looking for CSV which should like below

```
header1, header2,header3, header4

value1, value2,value3,value4

value5,value6,value7,value8
```

I have tried to read the map (key, value) and writing to CSV files, but its writing to the format

header 1, value1

header2, value2

header 3,value3

header4,value4

header1,value5

like this below is the code snippet which I have tried for

```
(Map<String, Object> map : maps) {

 for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

w.append(entry.getKey()).append(",").append(entry.getValue()‌​.toString()).append(‌​"\n"); } }
```

Comment: How much could you afford for the solution? [so] is not software writing service. Please show us your effort and then ask again about solving the step you can't perform

Comment: I have tried to read the map (key, value) and writing to CSV files, but its writing to the format
 header 1, value1
header2, value2
header 3,value3
header4,value4
header1,value5
like this

below is the code snippet which I have tried 
  for (Map<String, Object> map : maps) {

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

             w.append(entry.getKey()).append(",").append(entry.getValue().toString()).append("\n");

            }
        }

Comment: Most Maps are unordned. That means you can't iterate the entries in a consistant order.
Either use a LinkedHashMap or add all your Keys (Headers) to a list first and then iterate the Headerlist the get the Keys in a consistant order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will help you. It's not ready for your purpose. You'll need to change it, so it prints to a file instead of returning a `String`.

```
private static String toCSV(List<Map<String, Object>> list) {
    List<String> headers = list.stream().flatMap(map -> map.keySet().stream()).distinct().collect(toList());
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(headers.get(i));
        sb.append(i == headers.size()-1 ? "\n" : ",");
    }
    for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(map.get(headers.get(i)));
            sb.append(i == headers.size()-1 ? "\n" : ",");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

For the following input, it gave the following output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("header1", "value1");
    map1.put("header2", "value2");
    map1.put("header3", "value3");
    map1.put("header4", "value4");
    Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("header1", "value5");
    map2.put("header2", "value6");
    map2.put("header3", "value7");
    map2.put("header4", "value8");
    list.add(map1);
    list.add(map2);
    System.out.println(toCSV(list));
}
```

[image]

Such form is quite reversible, so you can write your own method to read from such CSV to a `List<Map<String, String>`

Another example, when key is not present in one of the maps:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your sample code snippet, but when I tried to use toCSV method, it is unable to resolve strem() method which is called against list
list.strem() and even keySet its unable to resolve.
Can you please comment on this

Comment: @user3655257 `streams` appeared in java 8. You can replace it with a `for` loop and construct a list of distinct headers by your own, but it would be better to switch to Java 8, as Java 9 is about to come.

Comment: @xenteros minor correction required it should be "map.keySet().stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())" not only toList()

Answer (score 1):

the following code solves your problem:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SomeMaps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<>();

        firstMap.put("header 1", "value1");
        firstMap.put("header 2", "value2");
        firstMap.put("header 3", "value3");
        firstMap.put("header 4", "value4");

        secondMap.put("header 1", "value5");
        secondMap.put("header 2", "value6");
        secondMap.put("header 3", "value7");
        secondMap.put("header 4", "value8");

        List<Map<String, String>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
        maps.add(firstMap);
        maps.add(secondMap);

        // extract all headers
        SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(firstMap.keySet());
        for(Map<String, String> map : maps){
            keys.addAll(map.keySet());
        }


        String header = StringUtils.join(keys, ",");
        System.out.println(header);

        // generate content of CSV file
        for(Map<String, String> map : maps){
            String line = getLineFromMap(map, keys);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    private static String getLineFromMap(Map<String, String> someMap, SortedSet<String> keys) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String key : keys) {
            values.add(someMap.get(key) == null ? " " : someMap.get(key));
        }
        return StringUtils.join(values, ",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following List

```
[
{
"header1": "value1",
"header2": "value2",
"header3": "value3",
"header4": "value4"
},
{
"header1": "value1",
"header2": "value2",
"header3": "value3",
"header4": "value4"
},
{
"header1": "value1",
"header2": "value2",
"header3": "value3",
"header4": "value4"
}
]
```

To covert this into a CSV file here I added a simple method....

```
public String createCSV(List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list) throws IOException{
    List<String> headers = list.stream().flatMap(map -> map.keySet().stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    String path= "dataCSV.csv";

    try(FileWriter writer= new FileWriter(path, true);){
           for (String string : headers) {
                 writer.write(string);
                 writer.write(",");
           }
           writer.write("\r\n");

           for (LinkedHashMap<String, String> lmap : list) {
                 for (Entry<String, String> string2 : lmap.entrySet()) {
                        writer.write(string2.getValue());
                        writer.write(",");
                 }
                 writer.write("\r\n");
           }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "File created"}
```

The file will get create and It should contains following entries from List

```
       header1  header2 header3 header4
        value1  value1  value1  value1
        value2  value2  value2  value2
        value3  value3  value3  value3
        value4  value4  value4  value4
```